# why i couldn't see any data in WPF Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grid, datatemplate

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tmpGrdProducts">


        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.RowSpan="6" Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Image>
            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProductName}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>

            <!-- Labels-->
            <TextBlock Text="SKU" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Code" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Mark" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Model" Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>

            <!-- Data-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SKU}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductCode}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mark}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model}" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"></TextBlock>

        </Grid>


    </DataTemplate>



</Page.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="grdProduct" DataContext="Binding">

    <ItemsControl>

        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tmpGrdProducts}"></ItemsControl>


    </ItemsControl>




</Grid>
```

---

**source code**

```
var Products = from t in bsEntity.ProductsTemps select t;

grdProduct.DataContext = Products;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the `ItemsSource` property of your `ItemsControl` to the collection.
Also inside your items control, you've declared an extra items control with the item template.

What you're looking for is something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollectionProperty}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <!--your data template here-->
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Also, I don't think you want `DataContext="Binding"` on your grid. If at all you'll probably need `DataContext="{Binding}"`

Comment: DataContext="{Binding}" is redundant. It's roughly equivalent to doing this.DataContext = this.DataContext in code.

Comment: @John Bowen. +1 for a Good point. Though since he was already attempting to set the datacontext the grid I thought i'd roll with it, not knowing the complete solution.